# Joda Time DateTimeZone

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I was going through [TimeZone page at joda website](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) and I came across this

```
-05:00  EST   
-05:00  EST5EDT   
-05:00  Etc/GMT+5
```

I just wanted to know what does that `EST5EDT` means, I generally use `EST` so was just wanted to know about it.

I have searched about it and found nothing before posting the question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EST5EDT and this one explains better what `EST5EDT` is http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.datetime/2009/03/msg7221.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EST - eastern Standard Time wihtout day light.
EDT - Eastern Standard Time with Day Light Saving Time

This is the short id of TimeZone that is used.

EST5EDT   means either in EST or  EDT ; value of offset in hours would be the same i.e. -5 hours.

Comment: Correct answer. Better yet is to avoid the 3 or 4 letter codes. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), usually continent plus city or region.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. `EST5EDT` is different from `EST` for the summer dates from 1967 forward, and for summer dates in WWI and WWII. `EST` ignores DST rules, `EST5EDT` applies DST rules as they existed nationally and retroactively uses `EST` for dates predating the establishment of timezones.

The `Region/City` style such as `America/New_York` will use nationally DST rules from 1967 on and during the world wars, use NYC DST rules for other times, and use local time in NYC for dates prior to the establishment of timezones.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into an issue with `US/Eastern`, `Americas/New_York`, and `EST5EDT`. Here is what I discovered.

For dates after the **Uniform Time Act of 1966** went into effect in 1967, these timezones are all identical. Also the US enforced standard DST rules during the World Wars, so they are all identical 1918-1919 and 1942-1945.

For any date before 1918, between 1920 and 1941 inclusive, and between 1946 and 1966 inclusive, `EST5EDT` will always be identical to `EST`. No DST is observed. Any date before 1883 Nov 18 12:03:58 will be treated as if the timezone EST existed.

Prior to 1967, `Americas/New_York` will provide the time **as observed** in New York City. So Daylight Savings Time will follow the rules in place by the NYC municipal or NY state government. Any date before 1883 Nov 18 12:03:58 will be in **local mean time** with an offset of -4:56:02 from UTC.

Here is a fragment of Ruby showing the difference:

```rb
# you may need to install the tzinfo gem with
# gem install tzinfo
require 'tzinfo'

# Using EST5EDT
# In 1966 DST is not observed.
Time.new(1966, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("EST5EDT"))
=> 1966-06-01 00:00:00 -0500

#  DST is observed in 1967.
Time.new(1967, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("EST5EDT"))
=> 1967-06-01 00:00:00 -0400

# Now with America/New_York
# DST is observed in 1966
Time.new(1966, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/New_York"))
=> 1966-06-01 00:00:00 -0400

# DST is also observed in 1967
Time.new(1967, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/New_York"))
=> 1967-06-01 00:00:00 -0400

# America/New_York yields local time for pre-timezone dates.
Time.new(1867, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/New_York"))
=> 1867-06-01 00:00:00 -0456

# But EST5EDT retroactively applies timezones
Time.new(1867, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("EST5EDT"))
=> 1867-06-01 00:00:00 -0500
```

Odd things can happen if you have multiple systems where one assumes `EST5EDT` and the other assumes `Americas/New_York`, especially when a system is storing `DATE` fields as `DATETIME` fields with the hours/minutes/seconds set to midnight. Data might look fine for anything recent. But a birthdate for example, from the summer of 1966 might get moved an hour, then truncated so it appears to be on the prior day.

And just for extra fun if you are dealing with old dates in Alaska, you need to remember that Alaska was Purchased from Russia. Dates before 1867 Oct 18 are **on the other side of the international date line and use the Julian, not Gregorian Calendar**. So Juneau, for example, went from 6 Oct 1867 (Julian) +15:02:19 to 18-Oct-1867 (Gregorian) -8:57:41. (The TZInfo library doesn't handle the Gregorian to Julian change.)

```rb
require 'tzinfo'

Time.new(1867, 10, 18, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/Juneau"))
=> 1867-10-18 00:00:00 +1502

Time.new(1867, 10, 19, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/Juneau"))
#error message
TZInfo::AmbiguousTime (1867-10-19 00:00:00 is an ambiguous local time.)

Time.new(1867, 10, 20, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/Juneau"))
=> 1867-10-20 00:00:00 -0857

# The Ruby DateTime datatype handles Julian,
# so convert Time to DateTime then to julian
Time.new(1867, 10, 18, 0, 0, 0, TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/Juneau")).to_datetime.julian
=> 1867-10-06 00:00:00 +1502
```